# Active a function with a button - jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, function

I would like to enable and disable a function with a button, is it possible in jQuery?

I need to track all clicks on a div, but only when the user want to record them.

1 - User click on button "start recording"
2 - every click on a div records the coordinates in a array
3 - when the user click on button "stop recording" the array is saved in a file and the function is disable.

For the example I did a function which just prints an alert with the coordinate.

```
$('.room').click(function(e) {
                var width = $(this).css("width");
                var widthLength = width.length;
                var height = $(this).css("height");
                var heightLength = height.length;
                height = height.substring(0,heightLength-2);
                width = width.substring(0,widthLength-2);
                var posX = $(this).offset().left, posY = $(this).offset().top;
                posX = (e.pageX - posX);
                posY = (e.pageY - posY);
                posY = Math.round((100/height) * posY);
                posX = Math.round((100/width) * posX);
                alert(posX + " - " + posY);
    });
```

and this is the div:

```
.room{
    position:relative;
    background-color:#444444;
    margin:5% 5% 10% 5%;
    z-index:1;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this you could just hold your array of points, and a boolean of whether you're recording. Push a new value into the array for each click - only when recording - and when you click stop do whatever you want with the array.

For example:

```js
var points = [];
var isRecording = false;
$('#start').click(function(){
    points = [];
    isRecording = true;
});

$('#stop').click(function(){
    isRecording = false;
    console.log(points);
});

$('.room').click(function(e) {
    if(isRecording){
      var width = $(this).css("width");
      var widthLength = width.length;
      var height = $(this).css("height");
      var heightLength = height.length;
      height = height.substring(0,heightLength-2);
      width = width.substring(0,widthLength-2);
      var posX = $(this).offset().left, posY = $(this).offset().top;
      posX = (e.pageX - posX);
      posY = (e.pageY - posY);
      posY = Math.round((100/height) * posY);
      posX = Math.round((100/width) * posX);

      points.push({x:posX,y:posY});
  }
});
```

```css
.room{
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  border: 1px solid black
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="start">Start Recording</button>
<button id="stop">Stop Recording</button>
<div class="room">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you could do sth as simple as this:

```
      var record = false;
      $('#yourbutton').click(function(e) {
        // toggle record true or false
        record = record ? false : true;
      });

      $('.room').click(function(e) {
          if(record){
            // only do your stuff if record is true               
          }
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow this steps:

- Have a global variable (Eg: `var canExcute=true`) In default you will able to execute the function
- Then check this variable before you run the function

```
if(canExcute){
       function_to_run();
  }
```

- After Executing set the variable to false (`canExcute=false`)

Hope it gives you the idea.

Answer (score 0):

you can declare a global boolean variable `beRecord`.
set true to it when you click the start recording button, and false to it on the contrary.
check the `beRecord` variable before record the tracking on your function.